# Deciphering .py Code

Tags: python

I am having a very specific problem. I use Putty for database management for my small business. We recently had an update and our normal command path to update our records is no longer in use.

We run Putty on all computers in store. Putty is used on a virtual machine with oracle. We have a main computer for the system in which the update occurred.

We normally input ~/Desktop/getdata.sh into putty using root user and it complies an updated list, creates a text file that we use. Unfortunately, the person who created this script no longer works with us.

I am trying to find a way to re execute this file again.

After the update, when we type in ~/Desktop/getdata.sh (after logging in as root) into Putty we get 'directory cannot be found.' I've searched everyday to find this file. However, I did find a getdata.py file and a getdata.bat files.

I can show both scripts if needed, I can update the question.

When I tried to run getdata.py I get

```
[root@RT_Store-01 /]# ~/Desktop/getdata.py
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
: command not foundta.py: line 5:
/root/Desktop/getdata.py: line 6: from: command not found
/root/Desktop/getdata.py: line 7: from: command not found
: command not foundta.py: line 8:
/root/Desktop/getdata.py: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/root/Desktop/getdata.py: line 9: `dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(_'file__))
```

Do I need to convert my files to .sh? How would I do that? Is this a bigger problem?

The script for getdata.py is

```
import os
import tempfile
import paramiko
import time

from pywinauto import Application
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class Connection(object):
    """Connects and logs into the specified hostname.
    Arguments that are not given are guessed from the environment."""

    def __init__(self,
                 host,
                 username=None,
                 private_key=None,
                 password=None,
                 port=22,
                 ):
        self._sftp_live = False
        self._sftp = None
        if not username:
            username = os.environ['LOGNAME']

        # Log to a temporary file.
        templog = tempfile.mkstemp('.txt', 'ssh-')[1]
        paramiko.util.log_to_file(templog)

        # Begin the SSH transport.
        self._transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
        self._tranport_live = True
        # Authenticate the transport.
        if password:
            # Using Password.
            self._transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
        else:
            # Use Private Key.
            if not private_key:
                # Try to use default key.
                if os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/id_rsa')):
                    private_key = '~/.ssh/id_rsa'
                elif os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/id_dsa')):
                    private_key = '~/.ssh/id_dsa'
                else:
                    raise TypeError(
                        "You have not specified a password or key.")

            private_key_file = os.path.expanduser(private_key)
            rsa_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(private_key_file)
            self._transport.connect(username=username, pkey=rsa_key)

    def _sftp_connect(self):
        """Establish the SFTP connection."""
        if not self._sftp_live:
            self._sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(self._transport)
            self._sftp_live = True

    def get(self, remotepath, localpath=None):
        """Copies a file between the remote host and the local host."""
        if not localpath:
            localpath = os.path.split(remotepath)[1]
        self._sftp_connect()
        self._sftp.get(remotepath, localpath)

    def put(self, localpath, remotepath=None):
        """Copies a file between the local host and the remote host."""
        if not remotepath:
            remotepath = os.path.split(localpath)[1]
        self._sftp_connect()
        self._sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)

    def execute(self, command):
        """Execute the given commands on a remote machine."""
        channel = self._transport.open_session()
        channel.exec_command(command)
        output = channel.makefile('rb', -1).readlines()
        if output:
            return output
        else:
            return channel.makefile_stderr('rb', -1).readlines()

    def update(self):
        """Execute the given commands on a remote machine."""
        channel = self._transport.invoke_shell(term='xterm')
        channel.exec_command('~/Desktop/update.sh')
        output = channel.makefile('rb', -1).readlines()
        if output:
            return output
        else:
            return channel.makefile_stderr('rb', -1).readlines()

    def close(self):
        """Closes the connection and cleans up."""
        # Close SFTP Connection.
        if self._sftp_live:
            self._sftp.close()
            self._sftp_live = False
        # Close the SSH Transport.
        if self._tranport_live:
            self._transport.close()
            self._tranport_live = False

    def __del__(self):
        """Attempt to clean up if not explicitly closed."""
        self.close()


def getData():
    """Create, get, and put delim file when called directly."""

    app = Application().start(r"c:\putty.exe trak@10.1.10.70 -pw trak")
    app.window_(
        title_re=".*trak.*").TypeKeys("/home/trak/Desktop/getdata.sh && exit{ENTER}")
    app.window_(title_re=".*trak.*").WaitNot("exists", timeout=120)

    trakfile = dir_path + '/storage/trakdelim.txt'

    shell = Connection('10.1.10.70', "trak", password="trak")
    shell.get('/trak/data/trakdelim.txt', trakfile)
    shell.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    getData()
```

I appreciate anyone who can help and I can clarify when needed!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Putty. Putty is simply a tool for logging into a remote server.

Comment: I am the least savvy as this goes, maybe I should put into question. I figured it had to do with putty since it is what we use to input the command into putty then we get our result of a text data. Like I stated before, the man who ran this script and knew more left. I am just trying to decipher. But tear me down. It'll really help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. There are bigger issues here that ought to be addressed (Why are random users running "magic commands" as root on a server? Why does root have a Desktop? How can (vital to the business) files just disappear? etc.), but that's both too broad and way out of scope for StackOverflow.

Comment: Your Python script (`getdata.py`) is meant to be run on Windows. All it does is use Putty to log into `10.1.10.70`, run `~trak/Desktop/getdata.sh` there, and download the resulting `trakdelim.txt` file. If `getdata.sh` is gone from the server, this won't help you.

Comment: That is helpful! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

A bit of googling showed me what this is:

Someone copied [this code](https://gist.github.com/AaronGhent/3430659) and wrote a simple script with it that takes a file (/trak/data/trakdelim.txt) on a remote computer with ip address 10.1.10.70 username trak and password trak and copies it to the storage/trakdelim.txt file. if this is not working for you now then take a tool that allows you to do this manually with such as [winSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) and use that instead.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. I am assuming that when the update happened, it deleted the file. We replaced the old harddrive with a new one before update. I am wondering if I can restore the content from the old to get the file.

Comment: Since you sometimes need to add things to start a python script python scripts are often initiated with a bash script (.sh) the bash script then contains something like: python getdata.py

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you! I think I've figured out the problem now!

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute it as a python script.

```
python ~/Desktop/getdata.py
```

Comment: I ran that and I got an import error about the module paramiko. Would I need to install this on windows cmd prompt?

Comment: You would need to use something like pip in cmd to install it. It would look something like "pip install paramiko". I HIGHLY recommend not installing random things if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: I am hoping to collect as much data as possible before performing anything! However, thank you for guiding me in some direction! I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. If you post the code of getdata.py I may be able to tell you what else you need to do to get it working.

Comment: You will need to install both pywinauto and paramiko with pip. I suggest looking for a tutorial on how to install and use pip.